Как в TreeView задать цвет каждому узлу через ViewModel?
Как привязать цвет из ViewModel к каждому узлу TreeView?
Я пытался через стили , но у меня получилось задать цвет только для всех узлов.
<TreeView Name="TreeView" ItemsSource="{Binding LeftTreeNodes}">
<!--<TreeView.Styles>
    <Style Selector="TreeViewItem">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
    </Style>
</TreeView.Styles>-->
<TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <TreeDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" >
        <Border>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Text}" />
        </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </TreeDataTemplate>
</TreeView.ItemTemplate>


internal class TreeNodeViewModel : ViewModel
{    
    private Color nodeColor = Colors.White;
    private string text;
    
    public TreeNodeViewModel(string text, Color nodeColor, string icon)
    {
        this.nodeColor = nodeColor;
        this.text = text;
    }

    public string Text => еуче;

    public Color Color => nodeColor;

    public ObservableCollection<TreeNodeViewModel> Children { get; set; } = [];
}


Не нужно задавать цветов во вьюмодели. Вьюмодель должна содержать какой то свойство - флаг, а уже на основе него через конвертер и выставить цвет.

У вас должно быть что-то такое, а не прямая привязка к цвету.

Если вы посмотрите на свойство Background чуть внимательней, то увидите [System.ComponentModel.Bindable(true)] public System.Windows.Media.Brush Background { get; set; }, что однозначно говорит Color тут совершенно не при чём, как минимум, тип свойства должен быть Brush
